# How to Html.ValidationMessageFor and popup window

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I am trying a register with popup window and ı am using Html.ValidationMessageFor but when I try to register under textboxfor there is nothing showing. can you help me ?

these are my code

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [jQuery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) in order to validate form fields as shown below:

***Step 1:*** Add the necessary `DataAnnotations` to the related `Model` properties as shown below:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required field")]
[MaxLength(50)]
[Display(Name = "Lab")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

***Step 2:*** Add the necessary script files to the `_Layout` or `View` page:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

***Step 3:*** Use the `ValidationMessageFor` annotation as shown below. Note that you can use some properties i.e. maxlength, etc. also:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { maxlength = "50", @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name, null, new { @class = "field-validation-error" })
```